# Why is Akasha considered as a basic element in the Vedas?

Tags: vedas, panchabhoota, akasha

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancha_Bhoota) wiki page mentions that the *Charvakas* did not accept Akasha as a basic element as it is not tangible and according to them, there are only four basic elements.

I would like to know why Akasha is considered as a *Bhoota* (basic element) according to the *Vedas*.

PS: I just would like to know the Vedic viewpoint (Uttara Paksha) before I delve into what Charvakas are saying (Purva Paksha). No disrespect is intended.

Comment: The material creation starts with Ether(sky); as in among 5 elements ; ether is 1st one to be manifested. in 12th canto of Bhagavatam anhilation process is given. So if you just reverse it; it becomes creation process. You can read more here http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/12/4/15-19

Comment: I do not know their view but some saints believe all 5 elements **Aakasa, Neer, Bhoomi, Agni and Vayu** are subtle elements. And we know periodic table has info about physical elements. Anyways, [Chidambaram Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thillai_Nataraja_Temple,_Chidambaram) has Aakasa Lingam where empty space (AAKASA) is worshiped as Lord Shiva. Lord Shiva here is Nataraja who is famous as Lord of Cosmic Dance.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Thanks for the link. Yoga Vashishtha also says the same thing. Although, I am primarily looking for references from the Vedas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Thanks for that piece of information. I also believe the same thing, I am just looking for references. Also, what periodic table are you talking about?

Comment: @AmitSaxena Modern periodic table. i'm not sure whether these elements  (such as iron, zinc, hydrogen etc..) also have subtle parts. But Some saints consider Plasma, 4th state of matter as Agni. But i don't think we can see their subtle forms without any spiritual virtues.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Oh no, you are mixing two different forms of classification into one. The basis of MahaBhootas classification is spiritual. The periodic table classification is based on the number of protons found in the nucleus.

Comment: @AmitSaxena That's what i said. Periodic table classification is Physical or Gross. But do these elements have subtle forms as fire or are they part of Earth or Space? Though scientific speculation is off topic here, and there should be some connection between gross and subtle forms of matter. I'm not mixing them but trying to understand them. What do you mean by spiritual? This spiritual has something do with Physical. Let's stop this here and continue in chat, if you are interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39549/discussion-between-the-destroyer-and-amit-saxena).

Comment: Akasa is the first subtle element created. The other subtle elements were created after Akasa. Akasa can be translated as space, sky, etc. Think about it. Before other elements are created, there needs to be space for them to exist in - that's why akasa is first. I'll look up some Upanishad references. You might do a search as this is similar to other questions previously asked.

Comment: @TheDestroyer do a search on this site. The gross elements should not be confused with the subtle elements. For example, the subtle element water does not correspond or map 100% to the gross matter called water, Don't let the use of the same words confuse you.

Comment: Akash is what...it is space...like in an atom its 99% is empty & that emptiness or space between 1 thing to other is akash...& god is said to be in that too...like he is just not in matter like nucleus & proton electron but in empty space too & space is a necessary thing...:)

Answer (score 6):

According to [Chhandogya Upanishad](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/chhaandogya.html?lang=sa),

> अस्य लोकस्य का गतिरित्याकाश इति होवाच
>   सर्वाणि ह वा इमानि भूतान्याकाशादेव समुत्पद्यन्त
>   आकाशं प्रत्यस्तं यन्त्याकाशो ह्येवैभ्यो ज्यायानकाशः
>   परायणम् ॥ १.९.१॥

[English translation](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-sama-veda/chandogya-upanishad/):

> I-ix-1: (Salavatya) 'What is the essence of this world?' 'Akasa' said (Pravahana); 'All these beings arise from Akasa alone and are finally dissolved into Akasa; because Akasa alone is greater than all these and Akasa is the support at all times.'

Adi Shankaracharya [Bhashya](https://archive.org/stream/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English_djvu.txt) on this verse:

> BHAYA- " What is the essence of this Region?"- " Akasha' '-said Pravlihana. " Akasha" here stands for the Supreme Self; as the Vedic Text says-' Akasha by name': as the producing of all things is the function of that Self, all 
>   things becorne dissolved into that Self. The Text itself is going to declare later on that "I  created Light. The Light becomes dissolved into the Supreme Deity. --**ALL these things in this world,-animate as well as inanimate, mobile and immobile-are produced out of Akasha,-in a regulated order of Light, Food and so forth, in accordance with the capacity  of things ;-they become dissoloed into Akasha, at the time of Universal Dissolution,-in the reverse order:-because Akasha indeed is greater than these-superior, larger, than all things**; and for that reason, it is the' param '-'ultimate'-'ayanam. -' substratum', basis, support, at all three points of time.-1)

Thus, Akasha is the greater/superior and supporter of all other elements and hence it is considered a basic element.

Also note that Akasha doesn't only refer to/as-an element, it is the narrator/signifier of Brahman according to Brahma Sutra 1.1.22:

> **आकाशस्तल्लिङ्गात्** ॥ १.१.२२॥
>   22. Space (Akasa) is Brahman, for Brahman's indicatory mark is in evidence.

Comment: The Akasha in that context is referring to Brahman, the questioner wants to know about the Pancha Bhuta Akasha.